# Finding non-recursive formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a recursive definition for a sequence, which goes as follows:

j0=18 j1=-11 jn=jn−1+jn−2

I have no idea how to create non-recursive formula. Is there anyone to help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Is the recursion meant to read $j_n=j_{n-1}+j_{n-2}$?  If so, then  this is the usual Fibonacci recursion (with different initial conditions) and you can apply the same techniques here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $$j_n-2=j_{n-1}-2+j_{n-2}-2,$$ this sequence can be reduced to Fibonacci (with different initial values, though).